# Update values in column using CASE

Tags: mysql

I have column of ages and I'm trying to add a column of age ranges based on the value in the age column. I have an `age_range` column and I was trying this:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET age_range = 
CASE WHEN age >=1 and age <= 24 then '18-24'
ELSE '' 
END AS age_range
FROM mytable
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS age_range
FROM mytable' at line 5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you dont need this here:

```
AS age_range
FROM mytable
```

try this

```
UPDATE mytable
SET age_range = 
CASE WHEN age >=1 and age <= 24 then '18-24'
ELSE '' 
END
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!